# What do you recommend for web development frameworks?

Tags: frameworks

I am evaluating web frameworks. The criteria is lightweight, secure, easy to learn and deploy. There're plenty, but I come up with the following short list,

1. web2py - the python version of "ruby on rails"
2. wt. - desktop version of web application
3. CGI/Perl - the old buddy

Have you worked with any of the above web frameworks and what's your experience? If not, which one do you recommend instead?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

This is a flame war in the making.

why did you rule out django and RoR, they have a lot more developer support.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluation of a framework is subjective. A framework is only as good as how good you are with a language, and best practices of a language. What works for one programmer or team, may not work for another, if the team is full of people new to the language.

Please rephrase your question, or rather think about if you really need a framework in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I find RoR feels very light and is easy to learn. I've also developed in several Java-based frameworks - though all feel heavier than RoR but certainly are rich in features.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to comment on answers. To answer Klochner, both seems quite popular but Ruby is not a language that I am familiar with and Django seems more heavy and complex to me than web2py.

Comment: According to the FAQ, you have to have at least 50 reputation to comment.  Then "add comment" will magically appear under answers and I expect the rest should be pretty straightforward.  On topic - not that I've used either - but from my quick looks at them, web2py seems more lightweight than django.  I've not looked at RoR, since I've not learned Ruby (yet).